# Lebesgue measure and area of a set

Tags: lebesgue-measure

So the question is something like this:
If a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a Lebesgue measure 0 and HAS an area. Does that area have to be 0?
Prove or disprove.

I know of counterexamples that don't even have an area defined but I figured that since the area exists there could be some way to connect it to the Heine-Borel theorem and conclude that, if there are countably infinite rectangles with a total area less than epsilon that cover the set, there has to be a finite subset with the same properties. I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: What do you mean by area?

Comment: Well, in my textbook it's defined as the integral of the set's characteristic function over a rectangle superset.

Comment: What integral? Riemann integral? Lebesgue integral? This assumes the characteristic function is integrable, right? What does that mean, precisely?

Comment: If a set $A$ has zero Lebesgue measure then $\int_A d\mu = 0$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. So any null set has zero area by your definition....

Comment: If the characteristic function is intergrable, then the set has an area and it's equal to that integral. It's a Riemann integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend knew the answer and it turns out I was right. If the set has an area, it means it's restricted (or what ever the English word is for a set that can be closed in a finite sphere). Then we have two cases. If it's closed, it's compact so Heine-Borel gives us a finite set of rectangles that cover the set.

If it isn't closed, it's "edge" (again, the terminology) has the Lebesgue measure of 0 so the union of the set and it's edge has the measure of 0 and is closed. Again, we can get a finite set of rectangles that cover that union, and then in turn cover the original set.

Comment: I think the word for "a set that can be closed in a finite sphere" is "bounded". And the word for it's "edge" is "boundary".